# Call WebAPI to .NET Framework from .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, web-services, devexpress

I have backend project on ASP .NET Core. I write a web api into this project. Also, I have UI project on .NET Framework. I want to call web apis from .NET Frameowork and use it. What's best approches is it?

Comment: Please be sure not to use the wrong tags. ASP.NET Core should be tagged as `[asp.net-core]`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Please see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically the part about research. Note that the specific language on the server does not matter for the client. So your question is more or less just, "[Call webapi from .net framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)".

Comment: Its depends on your requirement, Could you please share what you are trying to achieve? So that we can assist you. its really tough to explain all the best practices without knowing the context.

Comment: I have backend web api like post,put,delete. I am publishing on web abi using newtonsoft.json. I need provide on client side and use it at windows form. I am searching to way pull web api from backend. Am I explained well?

Comment: Yes you can consume `web api` service from your `windows from` using `HttpClient()`. For example on button click event you can write code for `web api` request. and bind that response on your from.

Comment: Hello was the problem resloved? Let me know if you require any further assistance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are trying to call `Web API` from your `Windows Form application`.

You can try this way:

On your Windows from Button Click event you can write this code snippet

```cs
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            
           
            string uri = "http://localhost:11951/api/MsAgent/GetMSAgentByAlias?alias=TestParam";
            var _http_response = _httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
            _http_response.Wait();
            var _read_response = _http_response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            _read_response.Wait();
            if (_read_response.Result.Contains("No Data Found!"))
            {
               // Your Logic what you would like to do when no response
            }
            
            
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MSAgentViewModel>(_read_response.Result);
            
            //Do what you wants to do with your API response
            //Can Bind Data With From Property
            
        }
```

This is one way, you can make the `API Service Class` in diffrent class its up to you. Lot of best practice out there. Let me know if you require more help on this.

Comment: I saw many different approches like this, it doesn't fully meet my demands. I want to do with return PostAsync but there are errors and I cannot handle it. Because of I cannot share a screenshot on a comment, I am writing here.                                                                
-> return await client.PostAsync<Interpolation>(client, apiAdd, interpolation, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());   Can I do something like that, because I have many apis which I have to provide on windows form client side.

Comment: Add your code here on your question to assist you better.